# How to restore panels in KDE?

Tags: kde, opensuse, user-interface

I accidently removed all panels (upper and bottom).
I use OpenSuse with KDE 3.5.
How can I restore them?

Comment: This is probably impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably iron your KDE settings in `~/.kde`, or selectively remove the ones that seem to pertain to the desktop shell. Sorry I'm not aware of an exact method, since I haven't used KDE 3 in ages. (You should upgrade to 4, it's stable enough you probably won't find many features lacking).